# Eclipse - Which project to choose to create HTML/Javascript project

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, project

When I try to create a web page with eclipse, I have two options
 -- Javascript project
 -- Static web project

If I choose the former, then configuring `run` to launch a web browser seems to be difficult.
If I choose the later, I lose support for JavaScript.

So, how do I get the best of both?

Comment: Use static web project and install your browsers debugging plugin (e.g. firebug for Mozilla firefox) to do the debugging of your js-code

Comment: But the reason I want javascript support in eclipse, is to take advantage of code-completion and as such

Comment: There is a plugin for eclipse that provides just that. Wait a moment please ...

Comment: Ok, I use a jsp editor, which is propably more, than you really need. But there should be an editor with js-code completion in the web tools project (WTP) plugin or its successor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been using the 'static web project' option, and I am including HTML, JavaScript and PHP files in the project.

Make sure you include your `.js` files in your `.html` document, otherwise check your eclipse software is up to date to ensure you are getting JavaScript support.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites

sorry would have put this in a comment, but I think I need more reputation.

Comment: did any of these links provide what you were looking for Karthik?

Comment: Hi guys. Sorry, was out the whole weekend. Using a static web project was perfectly fine. I was skeptical whether this will have javascript support, but all javascript files are being open in Javascript editor anyways. so, problem solved.

Comment: After creating Static Web Project - what would be the file extension of file I would add. Is it .html or what?